# Editable Queries Results QT SQLExress

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

Very new to QT and SQL, I've been working with QT for about 6 months, and just started working with SQL Express 2014. 
I've found that if I want to show a table and make it editable, the QSqlTableModel class does the job quite nicely. I'm working with a very large table, and in different sections of the program I'm building, various parts of the table need to be edited. I can show the various parts in a Query, with QSqlQueryModel class, but the query is not editable. I've tried using model->filter() inside the table class to edit out columns, but it seems to only filter contents in rows. 
Is there a way to view certain columns of a given table, and edit them?